# Rätz orthogonality and involution

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, functional-equations

In the Rätz’s sens of orhtoganality, can we find an exemple of an involution u(different to -Id)such that x orthogonal to y then x orthogonal to u(y)

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want an example for every Rätz's orthogonality or for some Rätz's orthogonality? Also, I guess you want to exclude the identity involution.

Comment: An exemple for some Rätz’s orthogonality, the involution should be not trivial like identity and -identity. Thanks